# Can calculus work on relations?

Tags: functions, relations

Until now I have encountered calculus on functions. But functions are also relations, what advantages does functions serve over relations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Functions and relations are different; a function maps $x$ to one $y$, but $x$ could be related to more than one

Comment: We *can* do calculus on some relations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function

Comment: on the other hand, what does it mean to do calculus on the relation 'equality', for example? or the relation $\{\} \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$? That's a perfectly good relation.

Comment: a function can't "jump over the same vertical line", so if you need some derivative at point $a$ and its image "jumps over some vertical line" you will have at least 2 derivatives

Comment: I think to "do calculus" you have to limit yourself (ha-ha, get it?  "limit" yourself...) to looking at single points of the relation and their immediate areas.  At that point (ha-ha, get it?  "point") the relation is locally essentially a function.  For example we can do calculus on a circle. If we focus on the point $(x,y)$ we are ignoring the point $(x,-y)$ and we might as well just be assuming the circle (or at least that little tiny arc of circle) is a function.

Comment: No.  Relations aren't single minded like functions.

Comment: If you are working with relations of the form $f(x_1 ... f_n) = 0$, where $f$ is a differentiable function, you can differentiate $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_1} dx_1 + \dots + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_n} dx_n = 0$, but in the end you are still piggybacking on the usual notion of differential of a function.